# phpmyadmin 5.0.4 does not run setup GUI

Tags: php, mysql, iis, phpmyadmin

When I try to reach http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php,
Phpmyadmin's setup page returns the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: preg_replace(): Argument #3 ($subject) must be of type 
array|string, null given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpmyadmin\setup\index.php:32
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpmyadmin\setup\index.php(32): preg_replace()
#1 {main}
thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpmyadmin\setup\index.php on line 32
```

That's all on the white Chrome page.
The PHPMyAdmin root directory is added to C:\inetpub\wwwroot as you may be noticed in the error and the IIS_IUSRS group got full permission over the PHPMyAdmin root directory and subdirectories.
Also, PhpMyAdmin is added as an application in IIS.
Thanks in advance.

```
The information you might need:
OS: Windows 10 build -> 19042
PHP: 8.0
Phpmyadmin: 5.0.4 all language version
IIS 10.0.19041.1
```

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16526

Answer (score 0):

Followed by this report at PHPMyAdmin GitHub page: [this link](http://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16526)

You should make some changes to file:

```
libraries/classes/Controllers/Setup/HomeController.php
```

as described in the link above and one more change you should make in file:

```
phpmyadmin/setup/index.php
```

if you are using PHPMyAdmin 5.0.4.
In line 32 as said in the error, surround the $page as the preg_replace() third argument with double quotations.

```
-$page = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $page);
+$page = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', "$page");
```

Worked for me.
Thanks.